# App Store Review and Watchkit

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, watchkit

I've uploaded an app that got approved with an apple watch version. But in the latest version, I want to upload it without the apple watch version. Does anyone have any information on this?

V1 = iOS + Watchkit
V2 = iOS only

Does anyone know if Apple would allow this? I've tried contacting them, no response yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes Connect does not allow uploading an updated version of an app when the update runs on fewer devices than the version of the app currently in the App Store. *This is by design*.

> An update to an app must work for every customer who has already
>   purchased the app, and is running a current version of iOS.

Developers who wish to issue updates, but remove device support, have three choices:

1. Fix their app so that it can work on the devices they originally set out to support.
2. Target a newer version of iOS that requires a newer device.
3. Remove their app from the store, and upload the new app with a different bundle ID.

↳ https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html